# How to assign something to nil using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using a Nuget bindings package in a Xamarin.iOS project, and I am running into trouble when attempting to assign an object to null. According to a link I found to the Objective-C version of the library, you can just assign the objects you want to disable to nil. Unfortunately, C# doesn't have a nil keyword, only null, and the library throws an ArgumentNullException whenever I assign one of its Properties to null. Does anyone know how to specifically assign something in Xamarin.iOS to nil instead of null?

Comment: Please provide the Nuget package name and the link you had followed!

Comment: I don't think the Nuget package is important in this scenario. That was background information. My question is how to pass nil in Xamarin.iOS, not how to do it for the specific library.

Comment: try NSNull.Null

Comment: I actually tried that, but the parameter in this situation expects a UIViewController. I can send null or a UIViewController, but since NSNull is derived from NSObject, then it is incompatible as far as I know.

Comment: I need to simulate your problem in order to figure out a solution for you. So I would need the exact way to produce this issue. Else it's tough job.

Comment: I already solved my issue by using a different solution. This question was more how to replicate sending nil in Objective-C using Xamarin.iOS in C#. I want to know if there's a way to do that or if it's just null. It could very well be that the creator of the library just didn't handle it correctly, but I don't want to assume that until I know for sure. There's a big difference between how Objective-C handles nil and C# handles null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem in the binding library.

When binding a library, the authors have to opt in to allow users to pass null to parameters, and it seems they forgot to do this (if they don't allow it, you get the `ArgumentNullException`you mention).

Contact the authors, and tell them they need to add the [`[NullAllowed]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference#NullAllowedAttribute) attribute on the property in question.