# AVAudioSinkNode in Xamarin.iOS can't connect to InputNode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

Using Xamarin, I'd like to use an AVAudioSinkNode to store and eventually transfer incoming audio data from a mic at the lowest latency possible (without going straight into AudioUnits and the deprecated AUGraphs). See my commented code below where the SinkNode is connected to the default InputNode. It's giving me grief. I'm using Xamarin.Forms with a simple iOS dependency class. I can successfully hook up an InputNode through an fx node (Reverb for example) and on out to the OutputNode. In this case, I've minimized my code down to focus on the problem at hand:

```
public unsafe class AudioEngine : IAudioEngine
{
    AVAudioEngine engine;
    AVAudioInputNode input;
    AVAudioSinkNode sink;

    public AudioEngine()
    {
        ActivateAudioSession();
    }

    protected void ActivateAudioSession()
    {
        var session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
        session.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DuckOthers);
        session.SetActive(true);
        session.SetPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.0007, out error); // 32 byte buffer, if possible!

        engine = new AVAudioEngine();

        input = engine.InputNode; // to save on typing
        input.Volume = 0.5f;

        var format = input.GetBusInputFormat(0); // used for fx connections, but not used in this snippet. If I use this in the Input -> Sink connection, it crashes.

        sink = new AVAudioSinkNode(sinkReceiverHandler);
        engine.AttachNode(sink);

        try
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            // Param #3 (format) is nil in all the Apple Documentation and multiple examples
            // In place of nil, **NSNull.Null** isn't accepted.
            // In place of nil, **null** throws a System.NullReferenceException. (see stack dump)
            // In place of nil, using the **InputNode's format** crashes with
            // something about missing the Trampolines.g.cs file... no clue...

            engine.Connect(input, sink, **null**); // null doesn't work in place of nil.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace); // Exception messages included below
        }

        engine.Prepare();
        engine.StartAndReturnError(out error);
    }

    private unsafe int sinkReceiverHandler(AudioToolbox.AudioTimeStamp timeStamp, uint frames, ref AudioToolbox.AudioBuffers inputData)
    {
        // Do stuff with the data...
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I found a post related to the use of **nil** as a parameter in Xamarin.iOS that says the author of the library needs to include the [NullAllowed] argument:

[How to assign something to nil using Xamarin.iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951327/how-to-assign-something-to-nil-using-xamarin-ios)

**My question is:** Am I missing something obvious, or is this an oversight in the Xamarin library definition? I always assume it's my lack of expertise, but if this is a bug, how do I go about reporting it to Xamarin?

**A follow up question:** If this *is* a glitch, is there a viable workaround? Can I go in and tweak the Xamarin library definition manually? (which would break on any updates, I'm sure.) Or can I make a little library using Swift which I then import into my Xamarin project?

Just trying to think of options. Thanks for reading! **Below is the Stack dump when I use null as a substitute for nil** (again... NSNull.Null isn't considered a valid type in this case. It just doesn't compile):

{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at AVFoundation.AVAudioFormat.op_Equality (AVFoundation.AVAudioFormat a, AVFoundation.AVAudioFormat b) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.3.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/AVFoundation/AVAudioFormat.cs:27
at AVFoundation.AVAudioEngine.Connect (AVFoundation.AVAudioNode sourceNode, AVFoundation.AVAudioNode targetNode, AVFoundation.AVAudioFormat format) [0x00024] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.3.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/AVAudioEngine.g.cs:120
at udptest.iOS.AudioEngine.ActivateAudioSession () [0x0009b] in /Users/eludema/dev/xamarin/udptest/udptest.iOS/AudioEngine.cs:43 }

THANKS!

Comment: 1) You should create a new issue @ https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues 2) I never used a `null` audio format, as a work around, what happens if you just pass a `new AVAudioFormat()` instead of `null` 3) if that does not work, how about a legit format such as: `new AVAudioFormat (44100.0, 2);`

Comment: Thanks, @SushiHangover for the suggestions! I haven't used null either, but it seems like this is the route for AVAudioSinkNode, since it doesn't allow for any format conversion. Doing an empty new AVAudioFormat gave me a different exception. And doing a legitimate actual format, as you suggested (as well as grabbing the format from the InputNode) crashes with the error: Trampolines.g.cs file not found -- I have no idea what that one's about :). Thanks for the suggestions! It gave me some hope! Any other workarounds are appreciated. In the meantime, I'll create an issue on the github.

Comment: In the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/avfoundation.avaudioengine.connect?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#AVFoundation_AVAudioEngine_Connect_AVFoundation_AVAudioNode_AVFoundation_AVAudioConnectionPoint___System_nuint_AVFoundation_AVAudioFormat_): `Connect(AVAudioNode, AVAudioNode, AVAudioFormat)` and there states that AVAudioFormat can be null.

Comment: Thanks for finding that, @Jack Hua! Does null translate to iOS's nil though? I've read that that's what NSNull.Null is for, but that doesn't compile being a type mismatch... I'm just confused why it doesn't work. Maybe there's something wrong with the way I'm handling the sink's delegate instead...

Comment: I will try your code later and update you.

Comment: Thank you so much, @JackHua-MSFT! Let me know if you need the full project. I'm wondering if the way I set up the delegate on the sink might also be an issue... any pointers would be fantastic. I'd love to avoid dipping back into the AudioUnit world, but will if that'd be best route for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug: The format parameter is [NullAllowable], but the current code to actually process that null wasn't linked up in the wrapper code. Here's the issue tracker on the Xamarin.Mac/iOS github repo:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/9267

Thanks for the github issue submission link, @SushiHangover!